# How to consolidate dates to parent object?

Tags: administration, database

On Account object I have Custom field: Support_end_date

I have a custom object called: license. On license I have a custom field called: license_end_date. Each license has a parent object: Account  (in a **lookup relation** NOT Master-detail so rollup summary is not an option)

it can happen that an account has several licenses. And here is where my problem starts:
- Account can have support_end_date of X
- every license has its' own end_date

I need to Update the database that Account will have the latest end_date from it's licenses (e.g. account suport_end_date will be the same has the license with the latest date)

- It seems that rollup summary fields are only available with Master-Detail relationships. [An idea request has been submitted](https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaView?id=08730000000BrqsAAC) on this, but no update yet.
- apparently I need that same functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. Change the Account to be a Master-Detail field on the License and then create the Account's support_end_date field as a roll-up summary field that is set to the maximum license_end_date of the child Licenses.  It is important that you change the field to Master Detail because the roll-up summary won't be available for what you are trying to do on a Lookup.
2. Create a trigger on the License Object that simply updates the Account's support_end_date when the License record's license_end_date is greater than the Account's support_end_date.  This would be a bit trickier too, when you start to think about having to handle deletes as well.

Clearly #1 is easier and if it doesn't make sense for a License to exist on its own without a parent Account then you probably want to make it a Master-Detail anyway.

If you cannot use #1 and need to update the current data you can either do it manually or through code.  Perhaps you could create a report to assist or data export to CSVs and manipulate with Excel to get a data load of Account objects.

For code, you could write something like the following or if you have [a lot of records](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm) look into using [Batch Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm) with your solution.

```
for (AggregateResult[] licenses: [    
    Select Max(License_End_Date__c)  maxDate, Account__c acctId
    From License__c
    Group by Account__c]) {

    List<Account> accts = new List<Account>();
    for (AggregateResult ar : licesnses) {
          Id acctId = (Id) ar.get('acctId');
          if (acctId != null) {
              Date maxDate = (Date) ar.get('maxDate');
              Account a = new Account(
                  Id = acctId,
                  Support_End_Date__c = maxDate
              ); 
             accts.add(a);
        }
    }

    System.debug('about to update accounts with max dates, Accounts=' + accts);
    update accts;
    System.debug('successfully updated accounts with max dates, Accounts=' + accts);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, #1 can not happen, as licenses can exist on their own. #2 is fine, but I need a solution for the current data as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a roll-up summary field on account that grabs the maximum support_end_date of the licenses.

Comment: The original question says that is not available due to the relationship not being Master-Detail; please provide instructions for a regular lookup if you know of a workaround.

Comment: I just didn't read the question carefully enough. Peter Knolle's answer is the correct one.